# Move the image around another image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitouch

I need to move the one image around other image where both images are in circle shape,they  should not collide or overlap with each other. I tried with **CGRectIntersectsRect** but no use of it because of corner radius of image i.e intersect function get called before they collide. [image] [image]

Comment: What's the question? I guess you want to know how to check if they collide? If so - and if both images contain circles in their center, just calculate the distance between both images and if distance < radius1 + radius2 --> collision.

Comment: @jimpic Thanks you for giving hint.actual i did it in another way must simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with animation but for this you should take it as single image as shown in 1st image and make different image with different position of blue image in circle.

```
loadingImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle7.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle9.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle10.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle12.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle13.png"], nil];

if(![loadingImageView isAnimating])
{
    loadingImageView.animationDuration=4;
    [loadingImageView startAnimating];

}
```

circle1.png,circle2.png,circle3.png... etc are images which contain blue and red image as  one image with different position of blue image in circle. Now hope if will helpful for you.If any problem is there then tell me.